# Can i step up a usb power oulet in my RV to power my cellular signal booster?

Tags: usb, dc-dc-converter, 12v

I have an RV with a 12V power system that has usb outlets to provide power for small devices.  I have a cellular signal booster that I want to power off one of the usb outlets.  The power cord is currently a 120v wall plug that outputs 12v 2A power to the signal booster.  I want to make a DC-DC step up converter to power it. I found one that will produce the 12v 2A output.  My question is will I burn out the  usb outlets?  Would a better solution be an inverter to just use the normal power cord supplied with the signal booster?  If so, will wiring the inverter straight off the batteries be ok, or will it get damaged when the RV is plugged into shore power and the 12v batteries are charging?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without intimate design knowledge or proper data sheets, it’s guesswork.

Comment: How much current does the device need? What is the USB charger rated for? Unless the power required is very low, the 12v line is probably a better source of power than a USB charger.

Comment: Typical USB outlets are either 100mA or 500mA so it is unlikely to provide enough power.  My phone charger can provide 1.5A but few devices can provide more than that.  If you have a cigarette lighter output these are typically 12V but check with the RV manufacturer.

Comment: You need 12V 2A to power the booster, right? Then forget about your "small device USB outlets" and just make a direct outlet to your 12 V RV power. No need in anything else, no converter-inverter ar anything.

Answer (score 2):

A USB port can’t supply that much power (2A @ 12V is 24W.)

In general, regular old USB is limited to:

- 2.5W (500mA) for 'official' USB2
- 4.8W (900mA) for 'official' USB3
- 12W (2.4A) for some chargers, but this isn't standard.

So, none of these are enough.

USB type C introduces higher power delivery using higher voltages than 5V, but this is an advanced capability and it's not likely your RV supports this.

Does your RV have cigarette lighter plugs? Those would work perfectly (oddly enough, my pop-up camper has both USB and lighter plugs.) If not, you could add that to your RV 12V power pretty easily.

The inverter approach can also work, but those things emit a lot of EMI noise (at least, the cheap ones do.)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get 2A at 12V on the output, you need at least 12/5 times amperes at 5V on the input, which is around 2.4 times or 4.8A. It would be extremely rare to find a USB outlet capable of providing that much current, so the answer to your first question is yes, you will likely burn out your USB port. And yes, it would be better to use the normal power cord instead.

As for connecting the booster straight to the battery, it depends whether its input power circuitry is robust enough to work with the whole voltage range of the battery while it's charging and discharging. If you gave us a detailed photo of its circuitry, we might be able to help you here.

Another option when going from the battery is to use a up/down DC-DC converter which would keep 12V on its output whether the input voltage is above or below 12V. You can find decent ones on AliExpress, just make sure you get one that is rated for at least 3A, basically in the 3-5A output range at 12V.